# How to spy on a function called inside class object

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, spyon

I want to test if `this.service.someMethod` is called using jasmine spy.

Source file:

```
// src.ts
import { Service } from 'some-package';

export class Component {
   service = new Service();

   callMethod() {
      this.service.thatMethod();
   }
}
```

Spec file:

```
// src.spec.ts
import { Component } from './src';

describe('test', () => {
   it('calls thatMethod of service', () => {
      let comp = new Component();

      spyOn(comp.service, 'thatMethod').and.callThrough();

      comp.callMethod();

      expect(comp.service.thatMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });
});
```

Output:

> Failed test: Expected comp.service.thatMethod to have been called.

Comment: Shouldn't `comp.thatMethod();` in your test be `comp.callMethod()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to refactor your code and take advantage of IoC (inversion of control) pattern. That means that you have to get rid of `Service` dependency in your `Component` class and inject it manually, like this:

```
export class Component {
   constructor(service) {
       this.service = service;
   }

   callMethod() {
     this.service.thatMethod();
   }
}

// Elsewhere in your code
import { Service } from 'some-package';
const component = new Component(new Service());
```

This approach will allow you to test your components effectively with `Service` mock:

```
import { Component } from './src';

describe('test', () => {
    it('calls thatMethod of service', () => {
        const service = jasmine.createSpyObj('service', ['thatMethod']);
        let comp = new Component(service);

        comp.callMethod();
        expect(service.thatMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });
});
```